# AWS DMS data transformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, transformation, aws-dms, dms

I see that we can create new columns during a DMS task using "rule-action=add-column" and "expression" to define the content of the new column. But what if we want to transform the data of an existent column?
Example: I want to encrypt a column during the migration. So, let's say, column "NAME". In the target, all records of this column should be filled with "XXXXX".
Is it possible?
Thanks!